# Sorting by one-to-many relationship and return distinct records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of IDs (page__96de2231 etc.) that I want to sort by a lookup on another table (where the property = "p_published_at", also including null values). I only want to return the IDs, properly sorted. But when doing distinct on the resulting IDs the order from the inner query is lost:

```
SELECT distinct id FROM (

SELECT entity.id, t1.property, t1.postgres_timestamptz
    FROM entity
    
    JOIN triple t1
    on entity.id = t1.subject
    
    WHERE entity.id IN ('page__96de2231', 'page__1fd94de8', 'page__898f13ec', 'page__81503fa2')

    ORDER BY t1.property='p_published_at' DESC NULLS LAST, t1.postgres_timestamptz ASC NULLS LAST

) as inner_query
```

How can I resolve this by either improving or refactoring the query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Ordering in sub-queries is never respected. If you need ordering, it MUST be done in the outermost query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return ids in a particular order, don't use a subquery. You need an order by in the outer most query.

In this case, you can use `group by`:

```
SELECT e.id
FROM entity e JOIN     
    triple t1
    ON entity.id = t1.subject    
WHERE e.id IN ('page__96de2231', 'page__1fd94de8', 'page__898f13ec', 'page__81503fa2')
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.property = 'p_published_at') DESC NULLS LAST,
         MAX(t1.postgres_timestamptz) ASC NULLS LAST;
```

By the way, you don't need a `JOIN` for this either:

```
SELECT t1.subject as id
FROM triple t1
WHERE t1.subject IN ('page__96de2231', 'page__1fd94de8', 'page__898f13ec', 'page__81503fa2')
GROUP BY t1.subject
ORDER BY COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE t1.property = 'p_published_at') DESC NULLS LAST,
         MAX(t1.postgres_timestamptz) ASC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very close to what I need I think!  I am trying with the second (no join) example but running into one issue:

If I add the columns like this I can see that the sorting is correct (all p_published_at) at the top and then sorted by date:

`SELECT t1.subject as id, t1.postgres_timestamptz, t1.property ... GROUP BY t1.subject,postgres_timestamptz, t1.property`

But if I only do this, the IDs are not sorted the same way:

`SELECT t1.subject as id ... GROUP BY t1.subject`

Comment: What seems to happen is that a later timestamp for an unrelated "property" gets sorted on top of the property we're interested in.

Comment: I am not sure if I'm on the right track, but could it be that I also need to add the filter for the MAX statement to make it respect this?

 `MAX(t1.postgres_timestamptz) FILTER (WHERE t1.property = 'p_published_at') DESC NULLS LAST`

Comment: @dani . . . Your code doesn't have a filter.

Answer (score 0):

One entity can have many triples. If an entity has two triples, one sorted at the beginning of the list, one at the end of it, where would you place the entity in your results? At the beginning or the end?

You can use `DENSE_RANK` to give the rows sortkeys. Then decide whether to take the minimum or maximum sortkey per entity:

```
select id
from
(
  select
    e.id,
    dense_rank() over (order by t.property = 'p_published_at' desc nulls last,
                                t.postgres_timestamptz asc nulls last) as sortkey
  from entity e
  join triple t on e.id = t.subject
  where e.id in ('page__96de2231', 'page__1fd94de8', 'page__898f13ec', 'page__81503fa2')
) ranked
group by id
order by min(sortkey), id;
```

(And Gordon is right of course, you can remove the table entity from the query; it is not needed.)